# FreeForm Pro, Dynamic Recipients field - where is this data stored?

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

I have a long dynamic recipients field defined for one form, and a client wants that same field in another form. Instead of re-typing it all manually I'd like to edit a database somewhere, but I can't find where this field is located. Can anyone point me to the right place? Using EE 2.7, FreeForm Pro 4.2.5

Answer (score 2):

Found it. You reference exp_freeform_forms for your form and identify the composer_id field. Then you reference exp_freeform_composer_layouts matching composer_id and get it from the composer_data field.